# What is the recommended Cordova way to store sensitive keys on Android?

Tags: android, cordova, cryptography, cordova-plugins, keychain

I'm using the Cordova Keychain plugin (http://plugins.telerik.com/cordova/plugin/keychain) to store some sensitive keys in the iOS keychain from my Cordova app. I would like to know of the best way to do this on the Android. I haven't had much luck finding any Cordova plugins for this purpose. I'm assuming I should find a plugin that leverages this : http://developer.android.com/reference/java/security/KeyStore.html

The only one I've found which I think might work is  : https://demo.a-sit.at/apache-cordova-cryptography-plugin/

What's the best way to do this? I need to store the key to my local sqlite encryption.

Thanks
Sam

Comment: Try that plugin (horrible code, but it has some kind of keystore implementation). Otherwise this is a question for a library which is off topic here. I can understand that this would frustrate you, but usually Google is about as helpful finding a library as us.